# mongoose object doesh't work like local object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using below function for building a tree list and is okey with local `obj_list` object, Why That not work with mongodb `doc` object?

**Code:**

```
const promise = Tree.find({uid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5c17974259bf01254c9c7f56')}, {'_id': false, 'uid': false}).exec();
promise.then(async (doc) => {

  const obj_list = doc; // not work with doc object in db
  const obj_list = [{    // work localy
    nid: 1,
    name: 'father',
    parent: '0',
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    nid: 2,
    name: 'boy',
    parent: '1',
    __v: 0,
  }];
  console.log(doc);
  console.log(obj_list);

  const obj_nested_list = [];
  let obj;

  function fill_with_children(children_arr, parent_id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < obj_list.length; i++) {
      obj = obj_list[i];

      if (obj.parent == parent_id) {
        children_arr.push(obj);
        obj.children = [];
        fill_with_children(obj.children, obj.nid);
      }
    }
  }

  fill_with_children(obj_nested_list, 0);

  console.log(obj_nested_list);
}).catch((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

**console.log(doc):**

```
[ { nid: 1, name: 'father', parent: '0', __v: 0 },
  { nid: 2, name: 'boy', parent: '1', __v: 0 } ]
```

**console.log(obj_list):**

```
[ { nid: 1, name: 'father', parent: '0', __v: 0 },
  { nid: 2, name: 'boy', parent: '1', __v: 0 } ]
```

**output with doc:** // not ok

```
[ { nid: 1, name: 'father', parent: '0', __v: 0 } ]
```

**output with obj_list:** // ok

```
[ { nid: 1,
    name: 'father',
    parent: '0',
    __v: 0,
    children: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose query promises resolve to a `Document` object, not a plain JavaScript object. If you want a plain JavaScript object to manipulate and log, you should use [`Query#lean`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean):

```
const promise = Tree.find(…).lean().exec();
promise.then(…);
```